# Convert VB.NET to either C, C++, or Java

Tags: java, c++, c, vb.net, converters

I need to convert VB.NET to any of C, C++, or Java.  I really don't care how many steps to take, and I am aware that it is hard to convert away from the .NET Framework.

So, I need an easy (albiet time-consuming) way to convert, while going through any number of languages between.  Remember the end result can be C, C++, OR Java.  Thanks!

Comment: Solution: Learn the languages, then convert. Easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the haxe programming language. I've never used it myself but it would seem that it can be compiled to JavaScript, Flash, NekoVM, PHP, C++, C# and Java (taken from http://haxe.org/). While VB.NET is not in there, C# can be pretty similar.

Comment: Well, I was looking for some kind of converting thing, but "a haxe is fine too".